# React Array.map rendering multiple components with events and how to access individual components

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

This is my first question. So greetings :)

I am, first of all, looking for good documentation or examples concerning this question. Perhaps, as I am new to reactjs, there is a canonical way to do this that im not familiar with. Any links to relevant material gratefully received.

So, what i want to do is very simple: array.map to render multiples of this component (a very simple blue box) which changes to gray when 'status' is clicked.

The problem I encounter is that clicking one box changes them all! I am absolutely sure this is quite a beginner problem. I have tried a lot of different experiments with 'ref' or using somehow trying to pass the key into statusClick().

There is an onClick attribute in the second  tag in the jsx.

How can it work so that in the rendered components from array.map, only the individual box behaves as described?

Here is the (messy) code.

````
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={colour:'DeepSkyBlue', status: 'active'}
    this.statusClick=this.statusClick.bind(this)
  };
statusClick(){this.state.status==='active' ? this.setState ({colour:'Gray',status:'inactive'}) :this.setState ({colour:'DeepSkyBlue', status:'active'})};
  render(){return(
    namesArray.map((namey,index) =>
    {return (
      <div key={index} style={{backgroundColor:this.state.colour, height:'180px',width:'160px',display:'inline-block',margin:'20px' }}>
      <p style= {{textAlign:'center',color:'white',fontSize:'20px'}}><br/>{namey}<br/> 
      {platArray[index].join()} <br/>  </p>
      <p style= {{textAlign:'center',color:'white',fontSize:'20px', border:'5px'}} onClick={this.statusClick}>{this.state.status}</p>
      </div>
    )
    }
  )
  )
  };
}```

Thank you very much for any input.
````

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You've only a single `state.color` value that you are applying to every element you map, so when it is toggled it is toggled for all of them.

## Solution

You should instead store a map, or dictionary of the elements you want to be "active" and use the alternative color.

So long as the `namesArray` isn't mutated (i.e. it doesn't have items added to or removed from, and isn't sorted) then the array index is ok to use as a React key.

Instead of of storing the color or status, store an object of active indices.

```
this.state = {
  // ... other state
  activeIndices: {},
};
```

Update the `statusClick` handler to consume an array index.

```
statusClick = index => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    activeIndices: {
      ...prevState.activeIndices,
      [index]: !prevState.activeIndices[index],
    },
  }));
};
```

And check the `activeIndices` state when mapping the elements to know what color style to apply. Pass the index to the `statusClick` handler

```
return namesArray.map((namey, index) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: this.state.activeIndices[index] ? 'Gray' : 'DeepSkyBlue',
        height: "180px",
        width: "160px",
        display: "inline-block",
        margin: "20px"
      }}
    >
      <p style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white", fontSize: "20px" }}>
        <br />
        {namey}
        <br />
        {platArray[index].join()} <br />{" "}
      </p>
      <p
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          color: "white",
          fontSize: "20px",
          border: "5px"
        }}
        onClick={() => this.statusClick(index)} // <-- pass index
      >
        {this.state.status}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help first off. I want to ask some questions about your rewrite of statusClick. When i evaluated the code, it returns 'activeIndices is not defined'. This line here is the line which apparently returns the error and, im sorry, but i cannot really understand this line [index]: !activeIndices.activeIndices[index],

Comment: @UnknownKnowns Ah, sorry about that, it was a bad copy/paste, it should be `[index]: !prevState.activeIndices[index]`. This line is simply flipping the boolean value stored in `this.state.activeIndices[index]`.